Why were the Starship booster and ship using LOX faster than CH4?
I have been analyzing frames from the video of IFT-6 (to extract the juicy data, though it might require more processing power than my PC can handle) and noticed something I do not understand. Note the levels of oxygen and methane:

In more detail:
 
The LOX levels in both ship and booster are lower than the CH4 levels!
For a fevered moment, I thought it might be related to active cooling:

When going to ~1750 Kelvin, specific heat is more important than latent heat of vaporization, which is why cryogenic fuel is a slightly better choice than water
Elon Musk on X

That 'victory' at figuring it out was brief, and shattered when I realised that even if this was some form of testing for future implementation of active cooling, there would be no need of it for the booster!
So, any ideas on why the Starship seems to be emptying the tanks of LOX faster than CH4?
Oh, and yes, the LOX tanks are larger, but the fuel gauges have been standardised to the same length, implying they are not depicting the remaining mass but simply a percentage of the full tanks.
Update: Snapshots of the Gauges

Seven snapshots of the gauges during the 6th IFT of Starship, from T+00:00:00 through T+00:07:50.
Update: Propellant Levels of Booster and Ship
These graphs show the propellant levels of the Starship booster and ship.
The booster graph starts at T+00:00:00 and continues until it returns to sea level.


The ship graph begins when the ship's outer engines fire for the hot staging and continues to the end of the initial burn.


Edit: 'burning rich'
Now that more than one comment has mentioned how 'burning rich' could be an advantage, I feel compelled to (check and) report that this situation could only be explained if the engines were burning lean. If they were burning rich (of fuel), the CH4 levels would drop faster than the LOX.

I wonder if it is related to boiloff and venting in the moments before launch. I suspect LOX escapes the vehicle more readily than CH4.

I know during engine shutdown they keep flowing CH4 after shutting off the O2 flow to burn off anything that could cause oxidation or make a bang on reignition... Maybe they're keeping a little extra aboard for that purpose?

Is the percentage difference consistent from near the start of the first stage run to near the end? i.e. is it actually using LOX at a greater relative rate, or is it starting with a relative underload of LOX?

@RussellBorogove Have to admit, I'm not sure. Today I'll prioritize parsing the information from those gauge displays and perhaps be able to give you a better answer, but until then the best I can do is to note that I've looked at frames from various parts of the video and it does seem consistently lower.

@DarthPseudonym Interesting thought! Yeah, I guess having excess oxygen around could cause some problems. Damn. You. OXYGEN! P.S. I'd vaguely wondered why liquid methane released on re-entry into an atmosphere containing oxygen would not immediately burst into flames. But I guess the rocket engineers have considered that!

@DarthPseudonym Actually it might be relevant. It segues with another odd thing I'd noticed during the engine reignition in micro-g. The ending ignition light indicator on the bottom panel turned OFF, the view changed to the engine bay, and there was some 'blue' venting from that engine.  The effect can be seen in this clip: SpaceX IFT-6 Engine Relight

@AndrewThompson Well, as far as reentry, it does burn! On IFT5 and 6 just before the braking thrust fires, you can see inside the booster skirt it's bright orange. I don't think that's just glowing from reentry heat, I think that's methane for the engine chilldown that's pooling and burning in the skirt area.

@RussellBorogove It looks to be the latter. Qn updated with 'Snapshots of the Gauges' at 7 times.
[I had intended to have numbers by now, but the calcs teasing gauge the data out, are failing badly. I was just preparing a fresh notebook to examine the problem in detail and extracted those seven images as a basic 'data set'.]

Maybe you need more thrust at sea level but more specific impulse at high altitude, so the fuel-richness is lower at sea level. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/why-is-fuel-ratio-different-for-upper-stage-of-a-rocket

I'm sure SpaceX has calculated things so as to carry as close to what's needed of either during the flight for the entire flight. I'd not be surprised if the fuel mixture at some stages of flight is more fuel rich and at other stages more oxidiser rich, and you're only comparing data (and rough estimates at that) from a short interval during the flight.

@RussellBorogove Graphs of CH4/LOX difference have been added. TL;DR I said I'd upload some graphs 18 days ago, and after wrestling for far too long trying to do it the (clever) automated way using software, I gave up and wrote a little app where I place the line of the level by eye using a spinner, and got the numbers from that.

Another benefit to burning rich is related to the molecular masses: O2 is 32, but CH4 is only 16, so in a mixture at a given temperature the velocity of the methane molecules is higher.
