# Why is the flame of the Falcon 9's 2nd stage (nearly) invisible?

Tags: falcon-9, upper-stage

During the first crewed flight of a Falcon 9 today, I watched the nozzle go from dark grey to glowing red hot, confirming that it was burning. Yet there were no visible flames. I understand this stage uses LOX / RP-1 for propellant, which is usually quite a show.

Why were no flames visible? I've attached a picture that I believe was from while the engine was about mid-burn. I can't verify that the picture is of the right time, but it looked like this through most of the burn today.

[image: Falcon 9 Second Stage]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a great question and I've often wondered this myself. It's the glowing soot particles in the kerosene + oxygen flame that make it visible, so the question is really why is there copious soot in the exhaust near the surface but more complete combustion in space?

Comment: different questions but you may find them interesting: [How do rocket propellant combinations rank in terms of “brightness”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20601/12102) and [How does the camera make the exhaust of the Electron's RP-1/LOX exhaust transparent?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32896/12102) and even perhaps [Is it possible to create different colors in rocket exhaust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36103/12102)

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/7751/are-rocket-exhaust-flames-ever-opaque, https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/why-do-the-exhaust-flames-from-cryogenic-stage-engines-appear-to-be-separated-fr

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Merlin engine used by the Falcon 9 burns a fuel-rich RP-1/LOX mixture, like most other rocket engines. That means the exhaust coming from the engine contains unburnt fuel, mostly in the form of soot. You can see that in your picture: There is a dark exhaust.

At sea level the excess fuel/soot burns off with atmospheric oxygen, leaving a flame trail behind the rocket, which you can nicely see after liftoff. But the higher the rocket flies, the less oxygen there is, the less visible the flame gets.

Now, the second stage operates in (near) vacuum, where no oxygen is, so the soot cannot burn at all, thus there is no flame.

If you would see a flame in the vacuum of space, that would mean that not all fuel/oxygen is burnt inside the engine, implying that the engine is not as efficient as it could be, since fuel burning behind the rocket does not provide any thrust.

Comment: How to reconcile these statements " That means the exhaust coming from the engine contains unburnt fuel," and "If you would see a flame in the vacuum of space, that would mean that not all fuel/oxygen is burnt inside the engine"

Comment: By fuel I mean RP-1 only, without oxygen. In the latter statement I mean RP-1 _and/with_ oxygen. Could try to phrase that better.

Comment: I did not know it burns fuel-rich. Why does it burn fuel-rich?

Comment: Almost all rocket engines run fuel rich. It makes for simpler molecules in the exhaust (e.g. CO instead of CO2), which don’t “hide” as much kinetic energy in internal vibrations; more of the kinetic energy goes toward thrust. (Many sources will say it’s *lighter* molecules that are desired but I’m told the math doesn’t work out for that explanation.)

Comment: @greg - see https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29580/26356 for some more info

Comment: @GremlinWranger That question is about cutoff, not steady state.

Comment: Fuel-rich combustion is also lower-temperature, so the combustion chamber cooling can be less extensive. Summary of pros and cons of fuel-rich here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26439/195

Comment: More of the same here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22123/195

Comment: I knew that fuel-rich improves specific impulse with LH2, but didn't know about the hydrocarbon one. "although the mechanism by which it does so is debated", so I guess I won't ask.

Comment: Of course, for anyone interested in propellants, [Ignition! by John D. Clark](https://www.amazon.com/Ignition-Informal-History-Liquid-Propellants-ebook/dp/B076838QS2) is well worth reading. It details why you want a rich mixture, and lots and lots of other fun trivia.

Comment: In addition, the vacuum nozzle expands the exhaust more, thus cooling it more

Comment: The combination of fuel and oxidizer would be called (bi-)propellant ;)

Comment: I think there is one more reason for fuel-rich burning. If the exhaust is oxygen rich, it has higher oxidizing power thus may easily damage the inner surface of combustion chamber or nozzle. I forgot whether I read it somewhere else or I made it up, and I do not know whether it is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

Too long to post as a comment.

See *Modeling of kerosene combustion under fuel-rich conditions* in [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319041043_Modeling_of_kerosene_combustion_under_fuel-rich_conditions) or [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1687814017711388) or in Advances in Mechanical Engineering 9(7) · July 2017

Also, from [Thermophysics Characterization of Kerosene Combustion](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20000065620.pdf) by Ten-See Wang l
NASA Marshall Space Flight Center, Huntsville:

> Soot Formation:
>
> Under fuel rich conditions, kerosene/RP-1 forms soot readily. This is because Naphthene and aromatic hydrocarbons form soot rapidly (condenstaion-polymerization) by directly condensing themselves into polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons (PAH). On the other hand, paraffins form soot slowly. This is because paraffins have to be break up into smaller fragments first, from which fusing of the fragments occurs to form naphthenes and aromatics, and PAH's form eventually and indirectly (fragmentation-polymerization). <sup>8,9</sup> These PAH's, also known as soot precursors, are then undergone a series of physical processes to form coagulated soot panicles. Frenklach et al.<sup>20</sup> developed a comprehensive soot formation mechanism in which 180 species and 619 elementary reactions are used in an attempt to describe the aforementioned soot formation processes. However, at the present moment, it is far too expensive to be incorporated into a CFD code while the oxidation of those 180 species was not even considered...
>
> <sup>8</sup>Lawver, B. R., "Testing of Fuel/Oxidizer-Rich High-Pressure Preburners,Final Report, NASA CR-16544, NASA-Lewis Research Center, May 1982.
>
> <sup>9</sup>Nickerson, G. R., and Johnson, C. W.,"A Soot Prediction Model for the TDK Computer Program," AIAA Paper 92-3391 ,July, 1992
>
> <sup>20</sup>Frenklach, M., Clary, D. W., and Ramachandra, M. K., "Shock Tubes Study of the Fuel Structure Effects on the Chemical Kinetic Mechanisms Responsible for Soot Formation, Part2," NASA CR174880,May 1985.

[image: soot formation chemistry in rocket exhaust as a function of fuel/oxygen ratio]