# InSight Launch - Centaur Fuel Rich

Tags: fuel, engine-design, atlas-v, insight, centaur

During [the launch of InSight today](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4_JNAFClFk) one thing sprung out to me: [at `T+408s`](https://youtu.be/O4_JNAFClFk?t=46m46s) the voiceover announces:

> Centaur slightly fuel rich.

And again [at `T+495s`](https://youtu.be/O4_JNAFClFk?t=48m11s):

> [Centaur] requesting a fuel rich condition at this point of the burn.

---

- What are the remedies of a fuel rich mixture and why would one not always use a perfect mixture?
- Why does it happen at this point in the launch?
- Why does it happen at *this* launch, I don't recall ever hearing that in another Atlas/Centaur launches.
- Why is this important enough to mention on the webcast - there are thousands of conditions and things changing with the rocket, why is this one important enough to mention.

Comment: for the first bullet, this is related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22122/merlin-engine-stoichiometry/22123#22123

Comment: I am thinking that this call relates to an abnormally fuel rich state, not a normally fuel rich state as explained in that link. Otherwise, there would have been no need for the call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Centaur upper stages have a Propellant Utilization (PU) system.  While [this document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19870006563.pdf) is old, the fundamentals apply.

> To  realize  optimum  performance  in  a  liquid-fueled  bipropellant 
>   space  vehicle,  it  is  necessary  to  control  both  propellants  so
>   as  to  deplete  them  simultaneously.  Such  a  simultaneous 
>   depletion  both  minimizes  vehicle  burnout  weight  (by  not 
>   allowing  any  unusable  amounts  of  one  propellant  or  the  other 
>   to  remain  in  the  tanks)  and  maximizes  the  mission  total 
>   impulse  (by  using  all  available  propellant  mass  in  engine 
>   reaction).
>
> Two  major  factors  influence  simultaneous  propellant 
>   depletion.  The  first  is  accurate  calibration  of  engine  mixture
>   ratios,  flow  rates,  and  total  thrust  under  flight  conditions. 
>   The  second  is  the  inability to  predict  the  relative  propellant
>   masses  to  be  loaded  at  lift-off.  Even  if  such  a  prediction 
>   were  possible,  uncertainties  in  determining  what  has  actually 
>   been  loaded  onboard  provide  the  second  large  error  source.  As
>   an  example,  for  the  Centaur  two-  burn  vehicle,  these  errors 
>   would  result  in  a  maximum  error  in  mass  ratio  of 
>   approximately  350  lb  at  burnout,  resulting  in  a  loss  of  350 
>   lb  of  payload  capability  from  a  mission  requiring  propellant 
>   depletion.    Clearly  then,  one  way to improve total payload capability is to provide some sort of system  for  propellant 
>   management.
>
> For  Centaur  the  first  function  of  such  a  system  for  proper  propellant  utilization  (PU)  is  to  measure  accurately 
>   the  ratio  of  propellants  in  the  vehicle  tanks  during  the 
>   entire  powered  flight  portion  of  the  mission.....
>
> The  second  basic  function  of  the  PU  system  is  to  control 
>   the  flow of  propellant  through  the  engines  to  adapt  the 
>   ratio  of  hydrogen  and  oxygen  to  the  amounts  remaining  in  the
>   tank.

The calls you quote are most likely reports of a slightly* anomalous condition in the PU system.  The flights where it wasn't mentioned, likely didn't have this anomaly.

*I say "slightly" because the launch was successful.